Node-red Modbus Flex Write node throws RangeError: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 255. Received 1604
I am trying to simulate a Modbus TCP server using node-red. This server has a large register set which is defined in a csv file. The csv file is of the following format. This is just first few rows. The rows can range from 500 to 3000 test datapoints:

The code for the function node to create simulated value is as follows (obj is the output of csv node which converts the csv to JSON):
var obj = msg.payload;

var valuelist = []
var addresses = 0;
var start_addr = obj[0].address;

function getRandomFloat(min, max, decimals) {
  const str = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(
    decimals,
  );

  return parseFloat(str);
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    addresses += obj[i].registers;
    msg.format = obj[i].format;
    msg.match = "none";
    if (obj[i].format == "INT16" || obj[i].format == "int16" || obj[i].format == "uint16" || obj[i].format == "UINT16") {
        var v = randomIntFromInterval(10, 20);
        valuelist.push(v)
    }
    if (obj[i].format == "INT32" || obj[i].format == "int32" || obj[i].format == "UINT32" || obj[i].format == "uint32") {
        var v = randomIntFromInterval(500, 600);
        //var buf = Buffer.alloc(4);
        //buf.writeInt32BE(value);
        //valuelist.push((buf[0] * 256) + buf[1]);
        //valuelist.push((buf[2] * 256) + buf[3]);
        valuelist.push((v & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
        valuelist.push(v & 0x0000FFFF);

    }
    if (obj[i].format == "FLOAT32" || obj[i].format == "float32") {
        var v = getRandomFloat(500.01, 600.01, 2);
        //var buf = Buffer.alloc(4);
        //buf.writeFloatBE(value);
        //valuelist.push((buf[0] * 256) + buf[1]);
        //valuelist.push((buf[2] * 256) + buf[3]);
        valuelist.push((v & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
        valuelist.push(v & 0x0000FFFF);
    }
}
console.log(valuelist)
msg.valuelist = valuelist;
msg.addresses = addresses;
msg.payload = { value: valuelist, 'fc': 16, 'unitid': 1, 'address': start_addr, 'quantity': addresses };
return msg;

The documentation of Modbus Flex Write node says the value array (from msg.payload before the return statement) can range from 0 to 65535 then why would it complain for smaller array?
The csv file that I am using results into an array of 802 elements.

